# I have one loop into another but they don't work as I expected

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to put one loop called j into another called i. In one of the ways I've tried the j loop end before the i loop and copy the same number each time because the i loop is no advancing.

```
For i = 2 To lastRowK
    For j = 5 To 500
    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = 7 Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 6).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

In the other option, I've tried to put a conditional for the Next j, but it gives to me a compile error: Next without for.

```
For i = 2 To lastRowK
    For j = 5 To 500
    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = 7 Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 6).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    If KRData.Cells(i, 5).Value = 7 Then _
    Next j
Next i
```

The third option I've tried is to put both of next in the conditional, but it returns a compile error: expected list separator or end of the statement.

```
For i = 2 To lastRowK
    For j = 5 To 500
    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = 7 Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(j, 6).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    If KRData.Cells(i, 5).Value = 7 Then _
    Next j AND Next i
```

Also, the end if or else are not working.

Comment: Check for `lastRowK` value, either use `Endif` with `If` otherwise use `If' condition  `then` statement  in same (single) line.

Comment: Examples 2 and 3 look weird to me because you cannot put a `Next` within an `If`-Clause.

Comment: Yes, I recently acknowledged the If/Next problem. I'm trying another kind of loops combined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `To` value `lastRowK` is set before the start of the loop. If its value is less than the initial value, in your case 2, the expression will evaluate false and terminate the loop.

```
For i = 0 To 3
Next i
```

Will loop until i = 4. It will then terminate the loop and resume execution at the next line of code following the `Next` statement.

```
For i = 2 To 1
Next i
```

In this example the loop will immediately terminate and advance to the the first line of code preceding the next statement. I’d be willing to bet if you put a breakpoint at the initialization of your loop, and the checked the local variables in the tools menu, you’d see that `lasRowK` has a value of `Empty` or less than equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you! But lastRowK has the integer value needed.